# Foundation 6 - breakpoint Mixin - "medium" not correctly set

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I tried to set a different font-size for the medium screens and smaller only:

```
// _settings.scss

$global-font-size: 100%;
$global-width: rem-calc(1000);
$breakpoints: (
    small: 0px,
    medium: 640px,
    large: 1000px
);


// _header.scss

.top-bar-left {

    h1 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;

        @include breakpoint(medium down) {
            font-size: 3rem;
        }
    }
}
```

The following CSS is generated:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 62.4375em)
.top-bar .top-bar-left h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

And it's the problem because I wants the medium size (640px <=> 40em not 62.5em).

Did I forget something ? in my settings maybe ?

**UPDATE**

My sass entry file :

```
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'settings';
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation';

/**
 * Foundation 6
 */
@include foundation-everything;

/**
 * App
 */
@import 'base';
@import 'header';
@import 'homepage';
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you are setting the breakpoint to "all of medium" ==> 640px to 1000px and "all of small" ==> 0px to 640px. Hence max-width = 62.4375em or 16 * 62.4375em = 999px.

If you're aiming for "from 640px down" then you just need:

```
@include breakpoint(small only) {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Which should evaluate to:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 39.9375em) {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Where 39.9375em * 16 = 639px.

**Edit**
Alternatively you can use the breakpoint function:

```
@media screen and #{breakpoint(small only)} {
    font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tested with `@include breakpoint(medium only) { font-size: 3rem }`, the generated CSS was `@media screen and (max-width: 62.4375em) and (min-width: 40em)`. Then I tried your fix (`small only`) but there was no generated CSS :s

Comment: Do you get an error when you build? Something like: `WARNING: breakpoint(): "small" is not defined in your $breakpoints setting.` I've added an alternative method above, but It is basically identical.

Comment: Same behavior... I updated my question the the sass entry file and this is the `_settings.scss` : https://gist.github.com/aguidis/234bdcbb8fb4fd1b54f8ff45dd167ae2

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this matters but in the original `_settings.scss` file the `$breakpoints:` settings have a `,` at the end of the last line (all their lists seem to).

Comment: Same behavior with the coma. When I use the `small` breakpoint there is no generated CSS... I don't understand ^^'